# Relationship between models are not working like expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 3 models that are basically nested.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :birthday, :name
  has_one :advancement, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :advancement
  attr_accessible :advancement_attributes
end

class Advancement < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :rank_name
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :rank, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :_rank
  attr_accessible :rank_attributes
end

class Rank < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :advancement_id, :one_li, :one_pi, :one_date, ...
  belongs_to :advancement
end
```

Here is the controller code I use to create my models.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.advancement = Advancement.new
    @user.advancement.rank = Rank.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.advancement = Advancement.new
    @user.advancement.rank = Rank.new

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the console I can create relations that work like I would expect.  When I try to do this through the browser all of my objects are instantiated, the foreign keys are correct, but if I try to find user.advancement, I get a method missing error.  Am I using new or create wrong and if so what should I do?  Sorry about the amount of code, but I didnt know any other way to explain it.

Comment: you pass wrong name, your `accepts_nested_attributes_for :_rank` should be `accepts_nested_attributes_for :rank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, in most of your code you reference a "rank" model but the model itself appears to be called "BoyScoutRank".  Could this be the issue?

Comment: Sorry, bad cut and paste issue.  That is not an problem.  I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

As Thanh pointed out, you have accepts_nested_attributes_for :_rank instead of :rank. You also should not need to create new Advancement and Rank models in your create.  The accepts_nested_attributes should handle that for you.

Does the following work (once you fix the :_rank issue):

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but it is not creating the supporting tables, only the main user.  What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What's your user form look like?  When you get the post to /users, what does params look like? (Should be in output of rails server or log/development.log).